# How to properly check multiple times statment

Tags: c++

```
if(a=='b' && b=='b' && c=='b' ...)
```

Is it the proper way to do this?

I already found other way to solve my problem but would like to know for future times how to do this

Comment: What are you trying to do? Verify that all those variables are equal to `'b'`? There's nothing _wrong_ with the way you're doing it. Personally, I'd encapsulate the checks in parens, even though they are not strictly necessary, e.g.: `((a == 'b') && (b=='b') && ... )`.

Comment: But if you have the option of putting all those variables into a collection of some sort, you could then iterate over them, which would make the code easier to maintain.

Comment: _"I already found other way to solve my problem but would like to know for future times how to do this"_ So you should document this in an answer here in 1st place.

Comment: if (('a' == a) && ('b' == b) && ('c' == c) && ...)     //to start a religious war ;)

Answer (score 3):

If all you have are discrete variables, then you'll have to do this check this way.

There are a few things you'll want to consider though:

It's bad practice to keep using `'b'` over and over and over. Either assign it as a constant or have all the other variables compare against the first one, so that if you need to change that `'b'` to a `'c'` you only have to do it once in the code.

```
if(a=='b' && a == b && a == c && a == d/*...*/)
```

Also, this is still a lot of code to maintain. Depending on how long the chain goes (do you go up to `a==g && a==h && a == i` or further?) You might want to wrap those variables into a `vector` and iteratively check them.

```
bool equal = std::find_if_not(
    characters.begin(), characters.end(), 
    [](const char & c) {return c == 'b';}
    ) == characters.end();
```

Comment: If you're going to put the characters of interest in a container then you should probably also consider using `std::find`. You could also consider using `std::string` and use it's find member functions.

Comment: @JamesAdkison I wouldn't recommend using `std::string`, if only because it obfuscates the purpose of the container. The OP is referring to discrete characters, and for that situation, `std::vector` conveys the purpose of the container better than `std::string` does.

Comment: +1, Fair point about `std::string`. Could also consider using `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` to avoid linear search (if that could become an issue).

Answer (score 2):

if you'd like a succinct way to describe intent then a little pair of template functions can help you:

```
template<class X, class Y>
bool all_equal(X&& x, Y&& y)
{
    return (x == y);
}

template<class X, class Y, class...Rest>
bool all_equal(X&& x, Y&& y, Rest&&...rest)
{
    return all_equal(std::forward<X>(x), std::forward<Y>(y))
    && all_equal(x, std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
}
```

which allows code like this:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 10;
    int c = 10;
    int d = 11;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << all_equal(a, b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << all_equal(a, b, c) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << all_equal(a, b, c, d) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your way looks proper.  Some coding standards require extra parens like this

```
if((a=='b') && (b=='b') && (c=='b') ...)
```

I personally don't think that it is necessary, if you know your operator precedence.  see http://www.cppreference.com and search for precedence.